# Is there a way to make GIFs in R without the use of ImageMagick or other third party software?

Tags: r, imagemagick, gif

I have been attempting to generate a GIF from plots generated and saved in R. With the current system we have in place using *ImageMagick* comes at a great inconvenience. Is there any other ways or packages native to R that can create GIFs? I have researched on stack overflow and have only found responses involving *ImageMagick*.

Comment: If it helps, pngs are a similar form of file and are available in base R with the `png` function.

Comment: I am already using pngs as the save format for the plots that will be turned into a gif. Do you know of any way to convert these into a gif easily?

Comment: Here is a nice [superuser post](http://superuser.com/questions/71028/batch-converting-png-to-jpg-in-linux) on converting pngs to jpegs with imagemagick. I imagine swapping out jpeg with gif in any of the lines of code will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

There's no R built-in way to make gifs (to my knowledge) that doesn't rely on an external library to convert images saved as single frames into a gif.

For that conversion ImageMagick is probably most common, but there are other tools you could use as well. [The `animation` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/animation/index.html) system requirements suggests you could alternatively use it with `GraphicsMagick` or even `LyX`, or you could manually (or programmatically if you can roll your own API) use any number of [online tools](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+convert+frames+into+gif&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=convert+frames+into+gif).

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention your operating system, nor whether you mean simple, single-frame GIFs or animated GIFs. If you just want simple GIFs, you could use the **NetPBM** package which is much lighter weight and easier to install than **ImageMagick**.

So, supposing you have a PNG file called `input.png` and you wanted to convert it to a GIF called `result.gif`, you could do:

```
pngtopam < input.png | pamtogif > result.gif
```

If you want to do that from inside R, you would need to use the `system()` command:

```
system("pngtopam < input.png | pamtogif > result.gif")
```

---

As you can probably see, **NetPBM** converts all inputs to its own, standard, lowest common-denominator PAM format and from there onwards to all its known output formats, thereby needing only 2N conversions between the N formats it supports rather than N^2 conversions - sweet!

So, for 64 formats:

```
64^2=4,096   (conversions to write)
```

whereas

```
2x64=128     (conversions to write)
```